# OSX port forwarding to a VM via RDP

Tags: networking, macos, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, virtualization

My goal is to connect over WAN to a Windows VM via RDP.
The problem is that my new router HG633, does not detect the VMs as connected devices, therefore direct port forwarding to them doesn't work. (NOTE: the VMs have network access via the same router).

So I need a workaround to my issue by the more experienced users.

Host OS: OSX 10.11.6 / VMware Fusion 8
/ Guest OS: Windows Server 2008 (Using Bridged Network configuration).

1. Can I port forward external connections to OSX and then redirect the connection to my VM via RDP?
2. Or can I somehow tunnel it via SSH?

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "detect" what exactly do you mean? Most routers simply have you point a port to an IP.

Comment: In regards to this router HG633 it needs to detect a device as it is connected to the subnet, and only then you have the option to make a port forwarding rule for it. In other routers it is flexible and simple just input the IP for the forwarding but it is not possible with the HG633.

Comment: Is the VM using DHCP?

Comment: Nope, all internal static addresses.

Comment: If you figured out how the router is querying devices you could work from there. It could be an issue of the VMWare bridge blocking LAN broadcasts.

Comment: I run a packet trace on my OSX.
I noticed many Spanning-tree-(for-bridges) packets.
Then I pinged the router from the VM, and I could see the OSX sending ARP requests on the subnet. (I am not an expert in Networking, so I am not sure why I am seeing STP packets coming from the router).

Comment: I believe the router is querying the MAC addresses, when I tried to ping the VM from the router, I could see that the OSX sent an ARP request for the router address, once the ARP was responded then the Echo reply came from the VM.

Comment: Arp requests are sent commonly, there's no guarantee it was linked to the icmp request.

Answer (score 0):

An SSH tunnel would be easiest. To tunnel to the OS X machine from the WAN, over SSH, your command will look something like this:

```
ssh -L 9998:localhost:3389 user@yourdomain
```

You'll need port forwarding set up on your router to forward port 22 (SSH) to the OS X machine.

Once you've made the SSH connection that sets up the tunnel, connect to `localhost` on port `9998` with your RDP client.

Comment: Thanks for the input, however, it is not working for me.

Comment: I managed to forward port 22 to the OSX host, however, the tunnel part is failing on me. Do I need to have an SSH server on the Windows Server which I want to RDP to?

Comment: If on the OS X machine running the VM, you connect to `localhost` on port `3389` for RDP, then on the machine connected with SSH, you would connect to `localhost` on port `9998` after setting up the tunnel. How do you connect to RDP locally on the OS X machine hosting the VM?

Comment: No, I want to connect over WAN, from a Windows RDP Client to the Windows VM hosted on the OSX. I don't want to connect to the VM locally.

Comment: If you can't connect locally on the OS X machine, you can't tunnel to the RDP server. Tunnelling makes a port on the remote machine available as a local port on the local machine.

Comment: Yes thats what I thought, and thats why I asked for a workaround.
I guess I can setup a remote connection on the OSX directly (VNC) and then just access the VM like that. I just wanted somehow direct access to the VM over the WAN.